# How to save plotly offline figure inside jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I am using plotly to plot figure inside jupyter notebook. After re-opening jupyter notebook, all the figures are not shown. I am wondering if it is possible to save the figures inside the notebook after being saved, just like using matplotlib or seaborn. Thanks

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

#fig=make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig=go.Figure()

fig.add_scatter(x=differenced_data.index[-1*n_steps:], y=test.values,name='test data',mode='lines+markers',marker=dict(color='green',size=5)) #mode='markers','lines','lines+markers'

iplot(fig)
```